# How to make pagination for php data inside preprocess_paragraph_HOOK

Tags: paragraphs

I have data coming from External Entity (MongoDB) and I need to make pagination inside hook theme suggestion of a paragraph :

[image: code snippet]

Is there a way to use built-in pagination of Drupal in this scenario? thanks!

Comment: `$build['pager'] = ['#type' => 'pager'];`. https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21Element%21Pager.php/class/Pager. Scan the core folder for samples.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add Pager to a custom page?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/206169/how-to-add-pager-to-a-custom-page)